# pretend + noun vs pretend to + noun

Tags: difference, prepositions

What are the similarities and differences between [these definitions](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pretend), besides the existence of an object?

> 1.2. **pretend** [with object] =  Give the appearance of feeling or possessing (an emotion or quality); simulate
>   2. **pretend to** [no object] = Lay claim to (a quality or title)

[p 23](http://books.google.com/books?id=N5dnAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA53&dq=%22give+back+Ireland+to+her+hardy+and+brave+population%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kAdSVIboNoj58AW44YLoAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22give%20back%20Ireland%20to%20her%20hardy%20and%20brave%20population%22&f=false), *Select Speeches, Volume 1*, By [Daniel O'Connell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_O%27Connell):

> Yes, restore to Irishmen their country, and you may well defy the in-vader's force ; give back Ireland to her hardy and brave popula-tion, and you have nothing to dread from foreign power. It is useless to detain the meeting, longer, in detailing the miseries that the Union has produced, or in pointing out the necessity that exists for its Repeal. I have never met any man who did not deplore this fatal measure, which has despoiled his country; nor do I believe that there is a single individual in the island, who could be found even to **pretend approbation** of that measure. I would be glad to see the face of the man, or rather of the beast, who could dare to say he thought the Union wise or good — for the being who could say so, must be devoid of all the feelings that distinguish humanity.

Why not: **pretend TO approbation**?

Examples of **'pretend TO rectitude'** can be found [here](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22pretend+to+rectitude%22&oq=%22pretend+to+rectitude%22&gs_l=serp.3...7288.12358.0.12462.12.11.0.0.0.1.179.881.9j2.11.0.msedrc...0...1c.1.56.serp..12.0.0.ul4AOQ-NnPM). But why is **TO** necessary in these cases?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. The Irishmen are not *laying claim* to approbation, they are *simulating the appearance of feeling* approbation. By contrast, in the first two citations given in your Google Books links, the men are not *giving the appearance of feeling* rectitude of intention, they are *laying claim to **having*** rectitude of intention. "Approbation" is cast as a feeling (approval), and "rectitude" as a state (correctness).

Comment: @DanBron Thanks. Yet are the two related? http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lay-claim-to resembles the explanation for Definition 1.2 above?

Comment: Well, that ("*are they related?*") is a different question. But the short answer is *yes*. A quick-and-dirty device to remember the connection is try adding "*be*" or "*have*" after "*pretend to*": "pretend to *have* rectitude". See the connection now? In both cases, you're *intentionally presenting false information*.

Comment: Interestingly, _approbation_ is just a nominalised verb, so that verb phrase is doing the same thing as _pretend to approbate_, but in fewer words - makes it sound more "academic" and "formal".

Answer (score -1):

Drop me a comment if I've completely misinterpreted this, but isn't it just a noun vs verb thing?

Like, every infinitive in English is defined by 'to something' so to 'pretend to' is always followed by an infinitive. And to use 'pretend' with a noun would then not require a 'to' simply because it's not a verb.

Is it that?

Comment: Thanks. I don't think that it's `just a noun vs verb thing`, because 'pretend' can be followed directly by a noun, as my quote above shows?

Comment: Good point. I have no idea then. The examples I had a scan through don't seem to show any kind of pattern which makes me think it's an optional word, but don't hold me to it.