# appear + noun vs appear as + noun

Tags: difference, conjunctions, archaic-language

Are they both right? What are the similarities and differences? Also, what's this phenomenon called?
I exemplify with **design** as the noun, but please feel free to cite better examples.

[Source:](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it+appears+a+meaning%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22it+appears+a+design%22) [p 116](http://books.google.com/books?id=MF1pkvnLxjAC&pg=PA116&dq=%22it+appears+a+design%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=66BNVLvnCZft8gW4zYKIBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22it%20appears%20a%20design%22&f=false), *History of England from the Fall of Wolsey*  ..., Volume 8, 
 By James Anthony Froude

> The Queen of England if trusted as a friend may and will do what she will never contract or bargain to do or submit to be pressed to do. It is a tickle matter to provoke sove-reigns to determine their succession.
>   ' Wherefore, good my Lords,' Cecil concluded, ' think hereof, and let not this your negotiation which is full of terms of friendship be converted into a bargain or pur-chase ; so as while in the outward face **it appears a design** to conciliate these two Queens and countries by a per-petual amity, in the unwrapping thereof there be not found any other intention but to compass at my Sove-reign's hands a kingdom and a crown, which if sought for may be sooner lost than gotten, and not being craved may be as soon offered as reason can require. (1564)

Source: p 29, *A Letter from a Gentleman in Scotland to His Friend in England*, ...,  By Charles Leslie

> Or would the Govern-ment of each Part of Great Britain he the more weak[e]ned, by giving an equal Capacity to all the QUEENS Subjects to Act for her Service, when Necessity shall require ? Otherwise **it appears as a design** to raise the Power of England, and to enlarge the Interest of it to our Disadvantage, by denying us the Privilege, which Reaon and Justice give us an equal Right to. (1708)

Comment: Please remove the extraneous hyphens from your quotes. This practice, particularly when [repeated](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37254/pretend-noun-vs-pretend-to-noun), can lead to "consistently low quality questions over time." If you are going to ask about lengthy passages, at least take the time to clean up the quotes before you post them. Also, there should be no blank space before a question mark.

Comment: I do not see anything amiss here. *As* serves its usual function of "in the form of/ as if it were, " which is needed in the second case but not the first.

Comment: *Appear* still takes this kind of complementation today, but it's quite rare.  It would be considerably more common to insert *to be* between *appear* and its NP complement. See Biber et al 1999 p.446.

Answer (score 2):

Both are right, but neither is very common today, at least in the U.S. The more common construction would be "appears to be [NOUN]." If you wanted to avoid the "to be" and make a construction a little more like this one that would still sound natural today, something like "seems a design" would work, though you could not say "seems as a design."